# Angular UI Google Maps : Flickering on drag

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angular-ui, angular-google-maps

I've made a stripped down fiddle, and you'll have to interact with the map to see the issue:

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/djohnston2014/86yj0dfz/3/)

You'll notice, or at least I hope you will, that if you make a quick drag, the map seems to flash completely gray for an instant. It does not happen every time, so you may have to quickly drag several times to see this. Furthermore, it seems to happen more frequently at lower zoom levels.

This is after the tiles have been cached, so it's not google maps fetching the tiles that causes this. Furthermore, I've tested the behavior on a standard google maps example and it does not cause this flicker. I think it may have something to do with `$scope.$apply()` being called from the directive and forcing a repaint, because I notice sometimes that the flicker happens while google is loading the tiles, i.e. the two events happen independently of one another.

While my last resort is to dig into the directive, this seems like a pretty fundamental problem from a UX standpoint, and I suspect that some of you must have run into this issue. Perhaps most importantly, the example at 
http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/demo does not suffer from this issue, though they have set a minimum zoom level, and so I wonder if this is simply a cheap fix for the issue I'm describing.

Thank you for any help you can offer, I've been tearing my app apart at the seams all day trying to pinpoint what's happening, and any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
why does stack overflow require a code-line for a jsfiddle link? seems totally contrary to the point of making a fiddle...
```

Comment: *why does stack overflow require a code-line for a jsfiddle link* ? Because when the fiddle isn't accessible someday nobody knows what you're talking about. The demo may also be done via a code-snippet

Comment: fair point, i stand corrected.

Comment: The example link that you have given has the same issue as well. If you try to drag the map at a moderate to higher zoom level. In fact, if you refresh the page, map shows the grey patches (which is basically tiles' rendering delay) at initial map load as well.